# Include key fingerprint in PuTTYgen app

Tags: c#, putty, keychain, ssh-keys, puttycyg

We have a C# application through which we send files (SFTP) to our clients.

One of our clients has provided us a private key as part of SFTP credential which is in md5 fingerprint format (hexadecimal).

Since we are using SharpSSH for transferring files, I have to include that private key but I need to first convert it into PPK format.

**My question is: Is there any way to convert a md5 fingerprint format into PPK file?**

I found PuTTYgen a little bit handy in generating new keys. It generates a new fingerprint when clicking on "Generate" button but I want to manually use the given md5 fingerprint key.

if it is not possible in the PuttyGen app, please guide any other way to do so.

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One of our clients has provided us a private key as part of SFTP credential which is in md5 fingerprint format (hexadecimal).

There is nothing like a private key in MD5 format. The MD5 is a fingerprint of a **public** key and MD5 is a one-way hash function (you can not create the original key from the hash).

> My question is: Is there any way to convert a md5 fingerprint format into PPK file?

No. Ask them to send you a private key, not a fingerprint.

> I found PuTTYgen a little bit handy in generating new keys. It generates a new fingerprint when clicking on "Generate" button but I want to manually use the given md5 fingerprint key.

Yes, it generates keys and can generate a fingerprints from keys. But not the other way round.